# Questions about snap

Tags: snap

I just installed libreoffice and other programs from snap, and I have two question right now:

1. It seems that the program cannot read anything outside of ~/snap/name_of_app/. I guess this is for security reasons, but...is there a way to read files outside of the folder? I mean, I put my stuff the ~/Document folder for example and I want the snap version of libreoffice to read it.
2. The libreoffice package doesn't come with Traditional Chinese as interface language. There's no lang pack I can install from snap. Any chance I can copy-paste the language files into some folders, or add my language in some way?

I'm running 16.04 x64 btw if that makes any difference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1, has an answer from our overlord: http://askubuntu.com/questions/821823/how-do-snap-applications-snappy-security-r-w-restrictions-and-user-files-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this should have happened automatically, but you can connect `libreoffice` to your `/home` directory manually. Open a terminal and execute the following command : `sudo snap connect libreoffice:home ubuntu-core:home`.

Check whether `libreoffice` was connected successfully to your `/home` directory by running the following snap command : `snap interfaces`

You can try to copy over the language files to the `/snap` directory, but I think that this is not a good idea, it might break things. Please bare in mind that snap packaging - just as [FLATPAK](http://flatpak.org/) for other distros - still is a relatively new technology.

Comment: Thanks. Now it can read files in my home folder, but i have another problem that it can't read a non-ascii folder...seems to be missing fonts. Guess I'll stick with the deb version for now.

Comment: @user541021 can you report a bug using `ubuntu-bug libreoffice` please and say that you're using the Snap? :) I know there's a lot of bugs in the LibreOffice Snap but the packagers won't necessarily find out unless we report them. Also don't report it to LibreOffice directly, they've said they're not responsible for the LibreOffice Snap. Indeed, can you report both these bugs (that /home should be readable by default and the ASCII problem) separately?