# Snap installed software unable to read from/write to secondary HDD [16.04]

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, mount, hard-drive, snap

I installed a piece of software ([CloudCompare](http://cloudcompare.org/release/index.html)) using snap as recommended. The issue is I'm unable to read from or write to the secondary HDD that I use as storage. When I use the file browser it's like it's not mounted. If I use a symlink it is blank in CloudCompare's browser.

What could be the issue with the setup? I simply did: `sudo snap install cloudcompare`

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Apparently snap apps can't write outside.

Comment: Hi @MichaelBay, do you know of a means to change the install location?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/821823/how-do-snap-applications-snappy-security-r-w-restrictions-and-user-files-work